# how to create css background effect in extjs4.0 application(on selection)

Tags: css, extjs4, mouseover

i am creating a application on extjs4

[image]

i wanted to attain the css selection mouse hover property on the textfields and combo box,the effect where.. background color can change on overcls in extjs

please help if you can't understand my question i will post it again!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

1. On your field config add your custom css class like this: `fieldCls: 'required'`
2. Create your custom CSS class like this:

   .required:hover {
           background-image:none;
           background-color:#FFFFCC;
    }
3. Include your custom css file on the page

Comment: well you did great and we need to define a different css for the field area particularly well and one more thing can we add anything related to mouse hover activity in new css

Comment: can you help in one more thing i am working on this attachment screen where user can upload various files,so i am planning to make it easier for user by adding cut/copy/paste method of file upload-er ,i will use a file area where user will copy the file from its os and paste its file path in the browser file attachment screen after that it will get uploaded

Comment: whats wrong with the regular file upload? In any case create a new question - if I can't answer it someone else will.